# trying to csv load relationships in NEO4J

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to csv load relationships. My nodes represent 80 priests and 200 churches. I am trying to do this - which works:

```
MATCH (p:Priest{name: "Baranowski, Alexander Sylvester" }),(c:Church{name: "St Wenceslaus"}) 
MERGE (p)-[:POSTED {posting:'1955-61', zip: '60618'}]->(c)
```

but with 800 rels.
My csv sheet has priests listed perhaps 10x and so need to connect to 10 different churches. 
My rels are years and zip codes. Nothing I have read and tried has worked. Ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.
put your CSV into the import folder of your neo4j instance.

```
load csv with headers from "file:///postings.csv" as row
MERGE (p:Priest{name: row.priest })
MERGE (c:Church{name: row.church }) 
MERGE (p)-[:POSTED {posting:row.posting, zip: row.zip}]->(c)
```

Comment: above solution returns 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.SemanticError: Cannot merge node using null property value for name'. All variations return errors or zilch. csv files are csvlint verified as proper.

Answer (score 0):

I assume posting is always present in the data.

```
load csv with headers from "file:///postings.csv" as row 
MERGE (p:Priest{name: row.priest }) 
MERGE (c:Church{name: row.church }) 
MERGE (p)-[rel:POSTED{posting:row.posting}]->(c)
On Create set rel.zip=row.zip
```